# Encrypt a value in MYSQL DB

Tags: java, mysql

I have 2 tables employee_master & user_master

Employee_id is a foreign key in user_master.

I need to encrypt the value of Employee_id while the value is being inserted into user_master table.

but the foreign key relationship should be kept... How can we do that

Comment: Why encrypt it in that case? In the case of someone getting into the DB what's to stop them simply doing `SELECT user_master.field FROM user_master JOIN employee_master ON (...)` to get the value of the encrypted employee id?

Comment: @ Matthew Scharley  can we keep the foreign key relationship  if we put encrypted employee_id into user_master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can't as if you will get an error.

```
Cannot add or update child row: a foreign key constraint fail......
```

The foreign key should have same value and type to its referenced field.

I'm not pretty sure with this, as an alternative you can refer to Bhushan post. Another is, make the foreign key as a normal field and let the query handle if the field is related to referenced field. But of course foreign key has other uses which a normal field doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some sort of intermediate table, which will have 2 columns: `Employee_id` and `Encrypted_empi_id` and then your `user_master` can use the corresponding `Encrypted_empi_id` as a key. I am not sure if this is a feasible model for you or not, just a thought.

You can use MD5 for getting encrypted version of emp id and can reverse the encrypted version to get back the exact original emp id.